# Encryption method that works both in ABAP and PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, abap

Is there is any encryption function that work in SAP and PHP, of course except using BASE64 encode-decode method.

The scenario is

1. ABAP encrypt string with key.
2. The string send to PHP.
3. PHP decrypt the string using key.

Thank you very much for any advise.

Comment: I've never tried it, but it seems ABAP has function modules to de- and encrypt data in AES. https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/26/aes-encryption-in-abap/

Comment: `of course except using BASE64` why don't you like base64? It seems the only [workable way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57366630/911419)

Comment: May I asked for the purpose? Is it really about storing encrypted information somewhere and decrypting them later in another system that is _not_ connected to the source system? If this is not the case I'd suggest to simply use built in transport encryption using TLS/HTTPS in the interface instead of using encryption libraries, which is still more error prone than trusting the built in transport encryption.

Comment: `DirkTrilsbeek` : i've  try that post,but in class **cl_sec_sxml_writer** threre is no method **encrypt_iv** , i already success with method **encrypt** but don't know what function used to decrypt in PHP.
`Suncatcher` : because base64 it is not encryption at all, it just an encoding that anyone can decode easily.
`konstantin` : _"Is it really about storing encrypted information somewhere and decrypting them later in another system that is not connected to the source system_" Yes, the system that we built with PHP just need to decrypt it and show the information base the decrypted string.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 doesn't an encryption method. @Dirk shared a blog post, which has information about `cl_sec_sxml_writer` class.

If your system hasn't got this class you can use [AES library](https://github.com/Sumu-Ning/AES). It has more capable than `cl_sec_sxml_writer` class. You can use ECB, CBC, PCBC, CFB, OFB, CTR encryption modes and None, PKCS #5, PKCS #7 padding standarts.

Another option is using `SSF_KRN_ENVELOPE` function for encrypt. It use RSA standart so result may be huge for ofen trasfers. It is using server certificate for encryption, you an check certificate in `STRUST` t-code. You check `SSF01` demo program.

Comment: Thanks @mkysoft, i already try in `Dirk` post, but there is no method **encryption_iv** as shown in that post.
I also already try your [link](https://github.com/Sumu-Ning/AES) too. But i read in the comment issue, it still have weakness when the encrypted string want to decrypted by openssl in PHP. The author just only fix for the decryption method part, not the encryption method part like i need.

Comment: I add another option and update my response. You can increase key length for increasing break time. Also padding algorithms get more secure encryption. Can you share direct link for the AES library issue?