# Encrypt or protect files with a password in ABAP

Tags: excel, encryption, abap, password-protection, password-encryption

My task is to encrypt files or protect them with a password and sent it as an Attachment via email.

I know there is a class **CL_BCS** which has the method **ENCRYPT** but the problem is, that we need an certificate for the recipient, which we don´t have anymore.

Is there a way to encrypt files or maybe make a .zip File and protect it with a password ?

It would be very helpful.

Thank you very much

Dear Andre

Comment: May be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756203/encrypt-string-in-abap-and-decrypt-in-javascript/57366630#57366630

Comment: @Suncatcher thank you. 
I will look into it.